# jQuery change height on dynamically written iframe

Tags: jquery

I am writing a widget: loaded with JavaScript then embed an iframe, so i can get jQuery support without problems and no CSS problems in the widget.

The widget is embedded onto sites like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _sid = '1';
  (function() {
    var se = document.createElement('script'); se.type = 'text/javascript'; se.async = true;
    se.src = '//xxxxxxx.com/loader.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(se, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Inside the `loader.js` i am writing an the following code to the page:

```
<div id="lHB" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; background-color: transparent; overflow: hidden; position: fixed; z-index: 10000001; display: block; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; height: 28px; width: 240px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;" class="_FloatingButton">
    <iframe id="_iframe" src="http://www.xxxxxxx.com/index.php" frameborder="0" style="background-color: #eee; vertical-align: text-bottom; overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; z-index: 999999;">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Inside my `index.php` is where i am filling the widget content, i do this with jQuery. The reason i am loading this from an iframe is to make sure that i do not get CSS problems and jQuery conflicts.

The index.php contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var _sid = '1';
  (function() {
    var se = document.createElement('script'); se.type = 'text/javascript'; se.async = true;
    se.src = '//xxxxxxxxxx.com/hello.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(se, s);
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `hello.js` dynamically loads the widget content onto the `index.php` page. Everything works great the only problem is:

I want to change the `height: 28px;` (loaded in `loader.js`) from `hello.js`. I have tried to find the

```
$('#_iframe', window.parent.document).css('height', 220);
```

But it wont find the `_iframe` :/

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you problem correctly, I had this same issue with having an iframe change it's height dynamically with it's containing page. Below is the code I used to accomplish this.

```
var iFrames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

function iResize() {
  for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
    iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
  }
}
if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) {
  $('iframe').load(function () {
    setTimeout(iResize, 1);
  });
  for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
    var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
    iFrames[i].src = '';
    iFrames[i].src = iSource;
  }
} else {
  $('iframe').load(function () {
    this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
  });
}
```

Of course you can change it from the tag name to the element ID. Just stick this on the top page which contains the iframe.

Comment: The problem is i cannot target the iframe from within hello.js since i am creating it on loader.js :(

Comment: ooh I see sorry I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code in document.load, to resize the iframe after loading the iframe content:

```
$(document).load(function () {
    $('#_iframe', window.parent.document).css('height', 220);
});
```

I have done the same with loading disqus comments in an iFrame.
Note: make sure you dont have the same origin policy

Comment: Is it impossible to change it from within hello.js? Inside hello.js i have my "up" and "down" buttons :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function in your widget script:

```
function resize_iframe() {
    var elem = window.parent.document.getElementById('my_ifrmae'),
        elem_height = $(document).height();
    $(elem).css({
    "height" : elem_height
    });
 }
```

Now all you have to do is to call the above function in a callback function in your origin script.

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this script and it's working perfectly for me. Feel free to use it!

```
function ResizeIframeFromParent(id) {
    if (jQuery('#'+id).length > 0) {
        var window = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow;
        var prevheight = jQuery('#'+id).attr('height');
        var newheight = Math.max( window.document.body.scrollHeight, window.document.body.offsetHeight, window.document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.document.documentElement.scrollHeight, window.document.documentElement.offsetHeight );
        if (newheight != prevheight && newheight > 0) {
            jQuery('#'+id).attr('height', newheight);
            console.log("Adjusting iframe height for "+id+": " +prevheight+"px => "+newheight+"px");
        }
    }
}
```

You can call the function inside a loop:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Try to change the iframe size every 2 seconds
    setInterval(function() {
        ResizeIframeFromParent('iframeid');
    }, 2000);
});
</script>
```